# why !, ", #, $, spc can resync characters in Asynchronous serial output?

Tags: ascii, microcontroller, uart

**Edit:**

All ASCII that starts with 0011 can resync frame. While other characters that starts with 01 can't and garbage results after closing and opening serial software. Now is the answer why more clear?

[image: more complete ascii]

I tried it out right out of the MCU hardware. A crystal running at 8 MHz. It's an old MCU.

Please try any MCU (even new ones) and send "Hello" and after the last alphabet "o", add "space" (or !, #, $) and compare this to using other characters. If you will use other characters (I used "|" for example in the following), the following garbage will result (after closing and opening the terminal software many times). All the serial software I tried have same results or effects.

[image: output with garbage]

In the following I used "space" (or !, #, $ will also work) that can somehow resync the word "Hello":

[image: output without garbages]

What kind of terminal emulator/software that can report any framing error and buffer overflow? The MCU I sent is old serial UART displayed in PC using serial to USB converter.

Better yet. Please share any software that can show how the UART receiver is receiving the patterns (with start and stop) bit so I can understand why some characters can attain frame sync in ANY terminals (I tried many like Teraterm, Serial Port Monitor, etc).

**Original message:**

I'm writing a program in the microcontroller that would output alphabet characters in the terminal like the world Hello using the ordinary asynchronous serial protocol (UART). I noticed that whenever I closed and opened the serial PC software while the MCU was running the same firmware, it can run garbage, this is because it can't tell which is the start bit and stop bit in the middle of the stream when the port opens.

But there is something so puzzling, whenever I used the characters "space", !, ", #, $ and add it to Hello() the stream can somehow resync itself. Is there any reason why these characters can do it? (Note the baud used is fixed at 9600, No Parity, Stop Bits and 8 bits for all cases. And firmware didn't use any delay loop in all cases)

[image: ascii table]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the number of stop bits and the exact sequence of characters you send. A bonus addition would be to show us the "garbage" characters, optimally with their encoding.

Comment: True, a continuous stream of "async" serial char frames cannot be reliably read by a UART when starting the read mid-stream, because it's simply looking for space bit after a stop-bit or marking (idle) condition. IOW any mark+space bit-pair looks like a good start bit. However I'm not convinced of your alleged claim that some specific char values can get the UART to attain frame sync. One issue is that you need a receiving program to accurately report `frame error` as they occur; typical terminal emulators are silent for any/all receive errors. Another issue is how exhaustive is your testing?

Comment: That ASCII table that you link to is woefully incomplete. It does not list all 128 characters for 7-bit ASCII codes. It's not even all the printable characters!

Comment: are you using an rc clock or crystal?   what software are you using, is there an operating system that cooks the data or are you taking this right out of the hardware?  are you getting framing errors?  are you overflowing the receive buffer?  you have provided no information.   the characters themselves cannot cause this from a hardware perspective.  so you need to look at what is wrong with your system or if you are using software that reacts to certain characters.

Comment: even with a crystal you can have problems if your divisor is making a frequency that is too far away from the other side.

Comment: So you have "Telnet" when it's okay and what is the settings when it's not? If it's the same, read how Telnet protocol works and how it mangles characters.

Comment: My testing is very exhaustive. Ascii that starts with 00 that always resync the character all the time. Is Tom V answer below the correct one? But sawdust insisting only the character FF can resync them. Can't you guys test this out by writing simple MCU program to send the text Hello (plus ascii characters with 00 or 01) output to the serial? Maybe if the baud is much much faster. It won't resync anymore? or no connection? Please someone write a second Answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The UART synchronizes on the falling edge at the start of the start bit.

Characters which have less other falling edges are less likely to cause mis-synchronation when a device starts listening to a busy line.

More significantly, characters which end with sequences that don't contain a falling edge will be more likely to allow a re-synchronization on the start bit of the *next* byte, whatever it is.

Since characters are output little-end first, to get the last wrong  falling edge as far away as possible from the right one, you need the longest sequence of zeros followed by ones.

If you are outputting 7-bit ASCII characters in 8-bit frames then the most significant bit will always be 0, so the best chance of resynchronization will be when there are more high-order zeros.

The printing characters with the most high-order zeros are punctuation and digits (note that digits are somehow missing from your ASCII table link).

Control characters have even more zeros, so horizontal tab or newline should resync you even more quickly.

Comment: "*characters which end with multiple high bits will be more likely to cause a re-synchronization*" -- Huh? Are you forgetting the proper bit order? Low-order bit is transmitted first! The only data byte that is going to aid in resyncing is a byte of all ones, i.e. 0xFF. Only the start bit is at space, and the rest of the frame is all marking until the next start bit. So whatever bogus frame alignment the UART is trying to use, the next start bit should be a real one.

Comment: You are correct.  Edited.

Comment: All ASCII that starts with 0011 can resync frame. While other characters that starts with 01 can't and garbages result after closing and opening serial software. Is the above answer the complete answer?